# Python Kubernetes Client: equivalent of kubectl get [custom-resource]

Tags: python, kubernetes

With kubectl I can execute the following command:

```
kubectl get serviceentries
```

Then I receive some information back. But **serviceentries** is a custom resource. So how do I go about getting the same information back but then with the kubernetes client?

Yaml looks like this for example:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: external-svc-https
spec:
  hosts:
  - api.dropboxapi.com
  - www.googleapis.com
  - api.facebook.com
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: TLS
  resolution: DNS
```

Anyone know the right method to use?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you should be able to pull it using the python client like this:

```py
kubernetes.client.CustomObjectsApi().list_cluster_custom_object(group="networking.istio.io", version="v1alpha3", plural="serviceentries")
```

That method applies to every custom resource within kubernetes and doesn't require any further definition to the python client.

Answer (score 3):

To take it 1 step further from Moshe Shitrit's very helpful answer, you need to examine the kubectl response to see what `apiVersion` to use, since it can vary by kind of custom object. For example, for virtualservices:

```
kubectl get virtualservices -o json

{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "networking.istio.io/v1beta1",
            "kind": "VirtualService",
            ...
```

You can see from the apiVersion within the `items` array that group should be: `networking.istio.io` and version should be: `v1beta1`. If you're listing the virtualservices for a namespace it would then be:

```
kubernetes.client.CustomObjectsApi().list_namespaced_custom_object("networking.istio.io", "v1beta1", namespace, "virtualservices")
```

Answer (score 0):

a snippet of a Python code for this:

```
from kubernetes import config, dynamic
from kubernetes import client as k8s_client
from kubernetes.dynamic.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError
from kubernetes.client import api_client
# Creating a dynamic client
client = dynamic.DynamicClient(
    api_client.ApiClient(configuration=config.load_kube_config())
)
custom_object_api = k8s_client.CustomObjectsApi()

namespace = "YOUR NAMESPACE"
# Fetching the "virtualservices" CRD list 
ingressroute_api = custom_object_api.list_namespaced_custom_object("networking.istio.io", "v1beta1", namespace, "virtualservices")
# you can add try-except block with ResourceNotFoundError exception
```

> if your resource is cluster-wide ( non-namespace scoped) use `list_cluster_custom_object` instead

same logic applies to other languages .

- [ref1](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md)
- [ref2](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/ecdbed0fe253fdbe60c70c732746de54123f1698/examples/dynamic-client/namespaced_custom_resource.py#L29)